# Access and return data of inner function in

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reading a CSV file, I can't return the data read. `console.log(data)` contains what I need, but it's not returning `data` (e.g. when calling the `readCSV` function):

```
export default function readCSV(filename) {
   let parser = parse({columns: true, trim: true, skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){
       console.log(data);
       return data;
    });

    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + filename).pipe(parser);
    return parser;
}
```

This gives me the parser instance and not the data - tried many variations of it. **How do I return `data`?** What am I missing as a concept in JS?
I'm using the [`node-csv-parse`](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-parse/blob/master/samples/fs_read.js) lib.

Comment: Since `parse()` behaves asynchronously, you won't be able to just `return` its result. The actual order of execution doesn't permit it. There are a handful of alternate options, each discussed in detail in "[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because `parse()` is an async function. You would either want another callback to retrieve the value, or use the new trendy approach of using promises:

```
export default function readCSV(filename) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let parser = parse({columns: true, trim: true, skip_empty_lines: true}, function(err, data){
       if (err)
           reject();
       else
           resolve(data);
    });
     fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + filename).pipe(parser);
   })
}
```

which you would then use a such:

```
readCSV("somefile").then((data) => {
   console.log(data)
})
.catch(()=>{
   console.log("Something went wrong")
})
```

Or use an async function:

```
async function doThing() {
   let data = await readCSV("somefile");
   console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Though, probably shouldn't swallow the error: `reject(err);`. Also, [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) could be useful here.

Comment: alright, this is under the assumption that the file is already loaded. Your example does not care for `createReadStream` (see [**here**](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-parse/blob/master/samples/fs_read.js#L9)). I fail to make it work with that, how do I build it in so that it reads from disk?

Comment: also, not sure if `parse` is actually async: https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-parse/blob/master/lib/index.js#L26

Comment: I just forgot to add that line back in